# EnterpriseDB ApachePHP - PHP not working

Tags: windows, installation, apache-http-server, php, enterprisedb

I realize there are a million 'php not working threads' on superuser, but none of them cover my situation, and none of the answers have solved my problem.

I installed apache/php on windows 8 as part of my postgres install - the application stack builder that came with it gave me the option to install them.

Long story short, apache works and serves content, but the php isn't working. When I navigate to a page with a .php extension through apache (localhost\phptest.php) the php remains in the displayed page.

The following lines are in my httpd.conf.

> LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
>
> AddHandler php5-script php
>
> AddType text/html         php
>
> PhpIniDir "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\php"

All file paths and files listed above exist. The php.ini file exists in the phpinidir.

*php -- ini* and *php -i* both give happy output when I am in the php directory. My PHP test file contains only the line , but even basic  doesn't get parsed.

I have installed php before with IIS, but never with apache. What am I missing to get this working?